# Which Wireless-N Routers are compatible with Apple products?

Tags: wifi, router

I have an iPhone 4, iPad, and MacBook Air, all of which support Wi-Fi 802.11n. However, there are many routers out there that were created before the official N spec was finalized (e.g. those based on drafts). How do I know which routers will be compatible with my Apple products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would be hard pressed to find a router that won't work correctly with the products listed. However, if you are concerned get any N router (non-draft) and you will be flying. As for features, I'd go for the cheapest router that supports a USB port (for connecting printers or scanners) and a few wired connections.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is buy an [Airport Extreme](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC340LL/A/AirPort-Extreme?fnode=MTY1NDEyMQ&mco=MTMzNzk2NTM)

Otherwise use the internet and read reviews.  Virtually any draft-N or official N spec routers will 'work'.  As with anything, the only way to be absolutely sure is to try them out.

Comment: Also a very expensive answer...

Comment: Yup but if he's got all those other expensive Apple devices what's one more?

Comment: The best solution. I have 2 Airport Express devices that run my Wireless N. Worth every cent, I hardly ever have to touch them.

Comment: @Diango Hardly ever? I've got a Cisco router and never touch it. Seems to me like Apple isn't even the best brand to select for routing equipment and the markup is a bit ridiculous.

Comment: You're probably right Kevin, Apple wouldn't be the best brand for routing equipment but the question was about compatibility and I think the airport extreme offers the user assurances in this regard

Answer (score 0):

All n routers should be compatible.

You can always check to see if they have firmware updates as well to bring them up from draft to spec and finally, unless all of the devices that are going to be using it are n (I'm thinking our Wii and wireless printer in the apt here), then you'll end up having to turn b/g on as well - which they all can connect to.